# Laravel Sanctum multiple guard/middleware

Tags: laravel, sanctum

I am using Laravel Sanctum and Vuejs. I want to login as administrator and user separately, and of course their requests shouldn't reach each other.

I have user (model and controller) and admin (model and controller)

this is how i log in (both controller separately like this)

```
public function login(Request $request) {

$fields = $request->validate([
  'username' => 'required|string',
  'password' => 'required|string',
]);

$admin = Admin::where('username', $fields['username'])->first();

if (!$admin || !Hash::check($fields['password'], $admin['password'])) {
  return response([
    'error' => 'some error'
  ]);
}

$token = $admin->createToken($request['username'])->plainTextToken;

$response = [
  'admin' => $admin,
  'admin_token' => $token
];

return response($response, 201);
}
```

I can use like this

```
// routes/api.php
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:sanctum']], function() {
 //
});
```

but what I really want to use like this

```
// routes/api.php
Route::group(['middleware' => ['admin:sanctum']], function() {
 //
});
```

I tried

```
  // config/sanctum.php 
  'guard' => ['web', 'admin'],
```

and also I defined custom guard

```
// config/auth.php
    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'admin' => [
           'driver' => 'session', // provider admin also defined and $table = 'admin' not admins
           'provider' => 'admin',
       ],
    ],
```

by the way when I tried to change driver like this driver => sanctum php artisan server:8000 dropped out.

Answer (score 5):

I encountered a similar problem while exploring Laravel 8 and Sanctum. I was able to make it work using Token Ability Middleware provided by Laravel Sanctum.

Here is how I think it can work for you.

In your controller, pass the role as ability while creating your token

```
public function login(Request $request) {

$fields = $request->validate([
  'username' => 'required|string',
  'password' => 'required|string',
]);

$admin = Admin::where('username', $fields['username'])->first();

if (!$admin || !Hash::check($fields['password'], $admin['password'])) {
  return response([
    'error' => 'some error'
  ]);
}

$token = $admin->createToken($request['username'], ['admin'])->plainTextToken;

$response = [
  'admin' => $admin,
  'admin_token' => $token
];

return response($response, 201);
}
```

Then you can use the Token Ability Middleware to identify the user role

```
// routes/api.php
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:sanctum','ability:admin']], function() {
 //
});
```

or

```
// routes/api.php
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:sanctum','abilities:admin']], function() {
 //
});
```

Similarly you can create ability for your User role.

Of course you will have to add the following to your $routeMiddleare in app/Http/Kernel.php for the above solution to work

```
'ability' => \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\CheckForAnyAbility::class,
'abilities' => \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\CheckAbilities::class,
```

You can learn more about this in official documentation
[Laravel Sanctum Token Abilities](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum#token-abilities)

Comment: it is looks like pretty good solution thanks for your reply. I also want to share my solution. I  also added a middleware line to $routeMiddleware array in app/Http/Kernel.php like this 'admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\Admin::class and after that created a middleware file which name is Admin.php just check auth and role column.

Comment: I can use Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:sanctum']], function() { }); and Route::prefix('admin')->as('admin.')->middleware(['auth:sanctum','admin'])->group(function()

Comment: I think this will only protect you if you are using token. but if you are using session you can't add abilities to session guards.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is easaly solved with Laravel Spatie.
Check this out https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v5/introduction. You can create roles & permissions and use CAN in your routes to distribute access along groups or single routes.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).